# what is changing on shape (rect) drag in Canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

How does it work?
a. The rectangle is changing place inside the layer?
or
b. The layer changes its place inside the stage?

I have drawn a rectangle, then I draged it to another place, and output the rect.getX() and rect.getY() . They allways remain (10,10).

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a rectangle, then coded the rectangle to be dragged, the rectangle shape will move. The rectangles x and y values should change.

You're saying this isn't the case? Paste some code so we can check it out :)